# C# MVC4 table with multiple submit buttons - always sends the same data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table inside my view that lists case details in each row. Every row has a submit button called "View Details". I have two hidden fields, TicketNumber and CaseId that are submitted when the user clicks the "View Details" button.

The problem is: it always sends the TicketNumber and CaseId of the first case in the table no matter which "View Details" button is pressed.

Here is the code of the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Case>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AbandonedVehiclesLandingPage";
}

<h2>AbandonedVehiclesLandingPage</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TicketNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubmittedOn)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewCase", "Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubmittedOn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.TicketNumber" name="TicketNumber" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.CaseId"  name="CaseId" />
                    <input type="submit" value="View Details" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Here is the receiving Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewCase(string TicketNumber, string CaseId)
    {
        string token = (string)Session["token"];
        if(token!=null)
        {
            if (provider.ValidateUser(Session["token"].ToString(), ""))
            {
                CaseService service = new CaseService("");
                CaseNote caseInfo = service.fetchSingleCase(TicketNumber, CaseId);
                return View("ViewCase", caseInfo);
            }
        }
        return Redirect(HttpContext.Application["connectUrl"].ToString()
            + HttpContext.Application["redirectUrl"].ToString());
    }
```

Last thing to say, it worked up until the point I lost the original View code and had to re-write it again. It feels like something small I am missing here.

Comment: Because your parameter is `string CaseId` and it would need to be `IEnumerable<string> string CaseId` because your posting an array of values

Comment: But what would be the point - what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Best guess is you want a form for each item, and declare it as `<td>@Html.BeginForm("ViewCase", "Home", new { TicketNumber = @item.TicketNumber, CaseId = item.CaseId }, FormMethod.Post, null) { <input type="submit" value="View Details" /></td> }` - no need for the hidden inputs

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I don't send or receive an IEnumerable of string CaseId. I send a single CaseId and TicketNumber of the corresponding Case.

Comment: You **are**  sending an array - for each item in your collection your generating an input with `name="TicketNumber"` and all of them are posted because you only have one form. Since `string` only allows one value, the `DefaultModelBinder` reads and sets the first one and ignores all the rest.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. I send @item.CaseId, where 'item' is a single Case instance and CaseId is inside that object. It correctly assigns the values. If I sent a list, it would result in an exception when it tried to post back to my action.

Comment: OMG. Read my last comment. you have one form generating multiple inputs with `name="TicketNumber"` and `name="CaseId"` - ALL of them are submitted!

Comment: And you have just accepted an answer that generate only one of them in a form proving my point (which happens to be the solution I gave you in an earlier comment)

Comment: Can you inspect the code I provided once more? I use a foreach loop to go through the Model, which is a list of cases. Each item inside that list is a single Case object. And I use hidden input fields that have a value of item.CaseId and item.TicketNumber, which reference the values of that object during a single loop iteration.

Comment: On a second inspection, maybe you are right. Though it doesn't send a list, it sends just the first occurrence of item.CaseId and item.TicketNumber.

Comment: Yes. Now I see. You were correct.

Comment: It does send a list! If you use you browser tools you will see that its sending `...CaseId=1&Caseid=2@CaseId=3..`. etc. Now using your code in the question, if you changed it to `string[] CaseId`, you would see that its now populated with all the `CaseId`'s of your collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your table as follows:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubmittedOn)
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewCase", "Home",FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.TicketNumber" name="TicketNumber" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.CaseId"  name="CaseId" />
                    <input type="submit" value="View Details" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```